# How to sum forloop values within Django template?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a Django template foorlopp like this:

```
{% load mathfilters %}

{% with summ=0 %}
{% for p10 in lines %}

    {{ summ | addition:p10 }}

{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

summ is zero at the end. How to summ all p10 values here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django template engine is rather limited; you likely won't be able to implement summation like this in the template itself.

You'll need to either do it in the view, or maybe create a custom template tag or filter for the cumulative sum.